# Ambiguous tag: p

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

The [p](/questions/tagged/p) tag looks like it's being used both for HTML `<p>` paragraph elements and for questions about P-NP.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p

It looks like the former (`<p>`) occupies the majority of its use.

Before I go make changes, I just want to get the support or anti-support of the community.

Answer (score 10):

It should be burned. `P-NP` problem questions should be retagged and the rest should be killed.

Encouraging tags for each HTML-Tag is a bad idea, otherwise I propose that the following tags also represent HTML-Tags:

- [a](/questions/tagged/a)
- [body](/questions/tagged/body)
- [head](/questions/tagged/head)
- [script](/questions/tagged/script)
- [style](/questions/tagged/style)
- [link](/questions/tagged/link)
- [form](/questions/tagged/form)
- ...

Comment: I agree with this. Might not hurt to have a different meta question to address the issue as a whole? That way we can reference it later, and it'll be easier to search for than this question.

Comment: @RobHruska: Well, can't hurt, yes.

Comment: Is burnination too permanent? What if we just discourage its use - what happens when the Next Awesome Language named "p" comes along? That's probably too special of a case to worry about. If it happens, someone will post here that they can't add the `[p]` tag and it'll get unburninated and used-appropriately.

Comment: If you want to create the other question, feel free to; otherwise let me know and I'll write it up. Here's some more fuel for it: [div](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63593/should-we-get-rid-of-the-div-tag), [table](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84594/should-the-table-tag-be-removed). It might be a little difficult to generalize the question. The best answer will probably be one that says each tag needs to be looked at case-by-case.

Comment: @RobHruska: You can call it a big clean-up for those (html) tags (have a look at the clan-up tag for inspirations). Also, feel free to write it, I won't have the time today to do that anyway.

Comment: I may not have time today either. Maybe later this evening.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend we:

- Update [p](/questions/tagged/p)'s wiki to say it should be used for `<p>`
- Re-tag the P-NP-related uses with something else. Perhaps [p-np](/questions/tagged/p-np) ?

Comment: Disagree.  A tag for a HTML element is stupid.

Comment: I'm not sure that can be made as a blanket statement. `[canvas]` might be a decent tag. I agree for `[p]`, though.