# Tag merge request: html-table and html-tables

Tags: support, retag-request

While reviewing [Should the [table] tag be removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84594/164291#84621) I came across this:

> [EDIT]
>   I notice that both [html-table](/questions/tagged/html-table) and [html-tables](/questions/tagged/html-tables) already exist. I would suggest these should be merged / aliased as well.

I checked on SO, and it looks like these tags are not synonyms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were only 13 questions tagged [html-tables](/questions/tagged/html-tables).  I've corrected them by hand.  There's no need for a synonym here, the New Tag Deletionist Cabal shall keep things in line.