# Older question (with answers) being closed as duplicate of newer question (without answers)

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I have just had ["Should the [table] tag be removed"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84594/should-the-table-tag-be-removed)? closed as a duplicate of ["Can we start cleaning up [table] tag and burninate it ASAP"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198024/can-we-start-cleaning-up-table-tag-and-burninate-it-asap)

The questions that was closed is 2 years old, the question that remains is 2 months old.   A case can be made for the newer question being better written, however the older questions has some answers unlike the newer question.

It seems that a lot of people just jumped in after the “first close as duplicate” vote without noticing the difference in the age of the questions – does the UI need changing on the close queue to make the age of questions and number of answers clearer to closers?

Comment: Actually it's totally legit if the newer question/answers are more complete. I'm pretty sure it was already discussed, let me search... by the way why [meta-tag:close-queue] tag?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha)

Comment: The linked dupe is perfect example, tons of older questions got closed as its duplicate, including even one [posted over three years before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1375/152859).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, look at this case, the newer quesion has no answers.   However there **are** times when it is clearly legit.

Comment: I thought there was a system in place that didn't allow to close as a duplicate when the suggested duplicate has no answers?

Comment: @Stijn there is on Stack Overflow, not on Meta. (not sure about other sites)

Comment: @IanRingrose your case is indeed somewhat different, but I still agree with closing yours (the older) as dupe of the newer, as it's better to "start over" in tag cleanup then resurrecting old posts.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, maybe the "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. " text that is used when a quesion is closed as a duplicate needs changing, or a differnt close reason for combiniing quesions on meta is needed

Comment: @IanRingrose agree about wording, better changed to something like "This question has been already asked and got answer" to address those cases. (or "asked elsewhere" maybe?)